# Send email from a react native app in background

Tags: javascript, reactjs, native

I want to send an email through a react native app when some action happens in background.

Comment: Learn how to ask a good question here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

I think you need a e-mail server or at least an email service to send an email with your app as I don't think you can send e-mails directly from the client side.

But there are various email services on the internet that you can use for free (like [Mailgun](https://www.mailgun.com/) or [SendPulse](https://sendpulse.com/)). There you can just use a simple POST method from the code in your app against their APIs.

There is also a react native SMTP module for react you can check out [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-smtp) for which you can use [this guide](https://anotherdev.xyz/react-native-smtp-send-email/) as the other answer suggested.

Answer (score 1):

***In case it helps anyone.***

To send email from react native app you need a service that would send the email for you. You can as well create your own service if you want.

If you wan to send email using SMTP protocol then you can use the [react native smtp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-smtp) module. You can read about it from [here](https://anotherdev.xyz/react-native-smtp-send-email/).